# Google Scripts HtmlService returns undefined form data

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a web app whereby a user fills out a form and the data gets populated into a google sheet. My problem is after I fill out the form the sheet gets populated with undefined data.

How do I define this data and append to a new row each time I fill out the form.

Example was taken from [here](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/).

Code.gs

```
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

function handleResponse(e) {

  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {

    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);


    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 

    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

    <script>
    var $form = $('form#test'),
    url = 'https://...';

    $('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var jqxhr = $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: $form.serializeObject()
     }).success(
      // do something
     );
    })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form id="test">
     <p><label>ID</label>
     <input type="number" name="ID"/></p>

     <p><label>Part Number</label>
     <input type="text" name="Part Number"/></p>

     <p><label>Description</label>
     <input type="text" name="Description"/></p>

     <p><label>Item Link</label>
     <input type="url" name="Item Link"/></p>

     <p><label>Supplier</label>
     <input type="text" name="Supplier"/></p>

     <p><label>Manufacturer</label>
     <input type="text" name="Manufacturer"/></p>

     <p><label>Pins</label>
     <input type="number" name="Pins"/></p>

     <p><label>Size</label>
     <input type="text" name="Size"/></p>

     <p><label>Order Number</label>
     <input type="number" name="Order Number"/></p>

     <p><label>Location</label>
     <input type="text" name="Location"/></p>

     <p><input type="submit" value="submit-form"/></p>

    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've borrowed code from another site it seems overly complicated for my taste.  Here is a simpler solution IMHO.  I don't see parameter e used anywhere so i removed.  Also the use of html form is not needed but I left it as is

Code.gs

```
function doGet(){
  try {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("HTML_Test");
  }
  catch(err) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": err}))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}

function submitData(data) {
  var shid = "your spreadsheet id here";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(shid);
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  try {
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,data.length).setValues([data]);
    return "success"
  }
  catch(err) {
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue(err);
    return err;
  }
}
```

HTML_Test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    <form id="test">
     <p><label>ID</label>
     <input type="number" id="ID"/></p>

     <p><label>Part Number</label>
     <input type="text" id="Part Number"/></p>

     <p><label>Description</label>
     <input type="text" id="Description"/></p>

     <p><label>Item Link</label>
     <input type="url" id="Item Link"/></p>

     <p><label>Supplier</label>
     <input type="text" id="Supplier"/></p>

     <p><label>Manufacturer</label>
     <input type="text" id="Manufacturer"/></p>

     <p><label>Pins</label>
     <input type="number" id="Pins"/></p>

     <p><label>Size</label>
     <input type="text" id="Size"/></p>

     <p><label>Order Number</label>
     <input type="number" id="Order Number"/></p>

     <p><label>Location</label>
     <input type="text" id="Location"/></p>

     <p><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()"/></p>

    </form>
    <script>
      function submitForm() {
        try {
          var data = [];
          data.push(document.getElementById("ID").value);
          data.push(document.getElementById("Part Number").value);
          data.push(document.getElementById("Description").value);
          data.push(document.getElementById("Item Link").value);
          data.push(document.getElementById("Supplier").value);
          data.push(document.getElementById("Manufacturer").value);
          data.push(document.getElementById("Pins").value);
          data.push(document.getElementById("Size").value);
          data.push(document.getElementById("Order Number").value);
          data.push(document.getElementById("Location").value);
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).submitData(data);
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      }
      function success(msg) {
        alert(msg);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant, works for me. Where would be the best place to find out how to have non-repeating values for certain columns then?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by non-repeating values.  Do you mean if an item number is repeated on the form don't add but update the row containing that id?

Comment: More like a primary key for a database is what I was thinking. So when the user enters an ID/Part Number/Link in the form, I want to be able to check the values that were input and if they are already present in the sheet, the form is refreshed displaying which fields had matching values with the google sheet.

Comment: I've shown how to get the row with a particular ID.  I've placed everything in a google doc file rather than put a lot of code here [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14NGMX6NckxiNHwG_so4RCVHjmWsIlvCvgjJKuq2-eIc)